# Sorting array based on a property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects based on a property value in that array. When I put a request to the API I'm using, this is what is returned to me.

```
0: {id: 23634, pollId: 6907, name: "B", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 341, …}
1: {id: 23635, pollId: 6907, name: "A", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 636, …}
2: {id: 23641, pollId: 6907, name: "C", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 246, …}
3: {id: 23642, pollId: 6907, name: "D", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 1092, …}
4: {id: 23643, pollId: 6907, name: "E", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 0, …}
```

I would like to sort the array by the value totalAmountRaised, from biggest to smallest. I am trying to use the sort() method to avoid writing a big complex function. This is what I'm looking for.

```
arrayToSort.sort((a, b) => (a.totalAmountRaised < b.totalAmountRaised) ? 1 : -1);

0: {id: 23642, pollId: 6907, name: "D", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 1092, …}
1: {id: 23635, pollId: 6907, name: "A", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 636, …}
2: {id: 23634, pollId: 6907, name: "B", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 341, …}
3: {id: 23641, pollId: 6907, name: "C", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 246, …}
4: {id: 23643, pollId: 6907, name: "E", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 0, …}
```

But, when I run the method, it only swaps the values of totalAmountRaised, it doesn't actually change the order of the array, which is what I'm looking for. This is what's actually returned.

```
0: {id: 23634, pollId: 6907, name: "B", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 1092, …}
1: {id: 23635, pollId: 6907, name: "A", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 636, …}
2: {id: 23641, pollId: 6907, name: "C", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 341, …}
3: {id: 23642, pollId: 6907, name: "D", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 246, …}
4: {id: 23643, pollId: 6907, name: "E", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 0, …}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [
{id: 23634, pollId: 6907, name: "B", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 341,},
{id: 23635, pollId: 6907, name: "A", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 636,},
{id: 23641, pollId: 6907, name: "C", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 246,},
{id: 23642, pollId: 6907, name: "D", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 1092,},
{id: 23643, pollId: 6907, name: "E", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 0},
]

let sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => b.totalAmountRaised - a.totalAmountRaised)
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: `array.sort()` sorts the array in place. No point in assigning to a new variable.

Comment: yes i just realized that after i comment... i edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

you don't need all this complexity `a.totalAmountRaised < b.totalAmountRaised) ? 1 : -1`

This should do:
`b.totalAmountRaised - a.totalAmountRaised`

All you need is this:

```js
let arrayToSort = [
    {id: 23634, pollId: 6907, name: "B", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 341,},
    {id: 23635, pollId: 6907, name: "A", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 636,},
    {id: 23641, pollId: 6907, name: "C", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 246,},
    {id: 23642, pollId: 6907, name: "D", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 1092,},
    {id: 23643, pollId: 6907, name: "E", type: "PollOption", totalAmountRaised: 0},
];
console.log(arrayToSort.sort((a, b) => {return b.totalAmountRaised - a.totalAmountRaised}));
```